# jquery browser and os detection which can detect android and iOs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Well i know there are many jquery plugins which can detect browsers such as Firefox , IE , chrome , etc ... And mainly 3 types of OS are supported by them i.e. windows , mac , linux.

I tested many plugins to detect my android but all failed.
Is there any plugin which can detect android os and then browsers such as android browser or opera mine and iOs and etc mobile devices such as black berry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html you can easily detect whether you are on iPhone or iOS. you may have to add Android to the entry and it would do it. Just print out the necessary attributes.

Hope this helps

Comment: I need something which can detect andro and iOs and blackberry , simbian etc.. and not just iOS

Comment: create a site and add the functions which are are on the link on an html page. Access the page from your device and that will give you the browser and the OS you are coming from.

Comment: I know how to operate this ... But it doesnt detects symbian  etc

Comment: check the navigator.userAgent and see what it prints. I know it works for iPhone, iPod and Android. Since I don't have a Symbian device, I can't test this.

Comment: I also dont have symbian and yea i fixed it to work on android and ios